# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::roles()

Tags: php, exception, laravel-4

I always get an error, when trying to use Eloquent's insert. What I want to achieve is to attach a given Role to a User. The User and the Role table has a Many-to-Many relationship.

```
User 1 - N UserUserRole M - 1 UserRole
```

The exception:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::roles()
```

Controller:

```
$user= User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'));
$user->roles()->attach(Input::get('role-list'));
```

User's role function (it is there...)

```
public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'UserUserRoles','User_id','Role_id');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be calling the method on a model and not the Query builder.

Try

```
$user= User::where('email','=',Input::get('email'))->first();
```

Comment: True, thank you! (I will accept the answer when I can)